# Duplicate WordPress site onto a staging site on a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a staging site for an existing WordPress site.
I've backed up the existing public_html folder through filezilla and it's about 25GB.
I've set up the subdomain on cpanel and also a new staging database.
I'm following these instructions - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/#stagingmanually
But the Duplicator plugin doesn't work on my wordpress site - I've even paid for the pro version but it fails at the Scanning part and never even gets to the Build part. I've been through the Help for Duplicator and they can't work it out either.
So ... my question is ... can I do this through cpanel and avoid the whole Wordpress dashboard completely. Can I just copy the files from the cpanel File Manager and put them into the Staging subdomain?
Or is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?
Thanks so much
Rebecca

Answer (score 0):

The free version of the Duplicator plugin doesn't allow you to create a package more than 500MB, you will have to do it on two parts by migrating only the database by the plugin and zip the files on cPanel and move the manually or using FTP.

You can zip the files and upload them to the new domain and export the database and open notepad++ for example and start replacing the old URL with the new one then import the edited database to the new domain